# Database connection pattern

Tags: database-connection, mariadb, connection-pooling, d, vibed

I use `mysql-native`. This driver is suppport `vibed`'s connection pool. On dlang newsgroup `mysql-native` developer Nick Sabalausky wrote:

"If you're using a connection pool, you shouldn't need to worry about closing the connection. The whole point is that the connections stay open until you need to use one again. When your program ends, then connections will close by themselves."

"You create the pool once (wherever/whenever you want to). Then, every time you want to use the database you obtain a connection by calling MySqlPool.lockConnection."

"Calling 'close' will always close the connection. If you got you connection from the pool, then it will automatically return to the pool when you're no longer using it. No need to do anything special for that."

The question about how pool should be done? I have read about singleton pattern and can't unserstand is it this case.

I wrote next code:

```
database class:
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import mysql;
import vibe.d;

import config;
import user;

class Database
{
    Config config;
    MySqlPool mydb;
    Connection connection;

    this(Config config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        mydb = new MySqlPool(config.dbhost, config.dbuser, config.dbpassword, config.dbname, config.dbport);    
    }

    void connect()
    {
        if(connection is null)
        {
            connection = mydb.lockConnection();
        }
        scope(exit) connection.close();
    }

}
```

users class/struct:

```
module user;

import mysql;
import vibe.d;

struct User
{
    int id;
    string login;
    string password;
    string usergroup;
}
    void getUserByName(string login)
    {
        User user;
        Prepared prepared = prepare(connection, `SELECT id, login, password, usergroup from users WHERE login=?`); // need to get connection accessible here to make request to DB
        prepared.setArgs(login);
        ResultRange result = prepared.query();
        if (result.empty) 
            logWarn(`user: "%s" do not exists`, login);
        else
        {
                Row row = result.front;
                user.id = row[0].coerce!(int);
                user.login = row[1].coerce!string;
                user.password = row[2].coerce!string;
                user.usergroup = row[3].coerce!string;

        logInfo(`user: "%s" is exists`, login);
        }

    }
```

The problem that I can't understand what is proper way to getting access to `connection` instance. It seems that it's very stupid ideas to create every new database connection class inside `users` structure. But how to do it's in better way? To make `Connection connection` global? Is it's good? Or there is more correct way?

Comment: I would suggest that more than 95% of users do not need connection pooling.  Suggest you avoid the complexity until you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope(exit) connection.close();
```

Delete that line. It's closing the connection you just received from the pool before the `connect` function returns. All you're doing there is opening a connection just to immediately close it again.

Change `getUserByName` to take a connection as an argument (typically as the first argument). Typically, whatever code needs to call `getUserByName` should either open a connection, or get a connenction from the pool via `lockConnection`, and then pass that connection to `getUserByName` and whatever other DB-related functions it needs to use. Then, after your code is done calling `getUserByName` (and whatever other DB functions it needs to call), you either just don't worry about the connection anymore and let your vibed fiber finish (if you're using vibed and got the connection from a pool) or you `close` the connection (if you did NOT get the connection from a vibed pool).

Comment: but how this code work if I am opening connection, that immediately close it and doing request. It should fail, but it's work...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to pass the connection to your functions that need it. So you would refactor your getUserByName() to take connection as an argument.

Another alternative is to use the [DAO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) . Constructor of your DAO class would take the connection as one of the main parameters, and all the methods would use it to do the DB operation.

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: DejanLekic, why what is the difference?

Comment: The difference between what? A Singleton and DAO?

Comment: DejanLekic, yes

Comment: DAO is a different kind of pattern. The DAO implementation CAN be a singleton, but I have never seen someone do it that way...